# How to import Webots controller in a Ros-python script

Tags: python-2.7, ros, webots

I want to write a controller in Python and trying to import Webots controller library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from time import sleep
from controller import Robot
```

and get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mine_controller.py", line 6, in <module>
    from controller import Robot
  File "/snap/webots/current/usr/share/webots/lib/controller/python27/controller.py", line 17, in <module>
    _controller = swig_import_helper()
  File "/snap/webots/current/usr/share/webots/lib/controller/python27/controller.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_controller')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: libCppController.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My environmental variables :

```
PYTHONPATH=/snap/webots/current/usr/share/webots/lib/controller/python27:/home/boand/workspace_ros/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/boand/workspace_ros/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib:/snap/webots/current/usr/share/webots/lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is wrong, `/snap/webots/current/usr/share/webots/lib` should be replaced by `/snap/webots/current/usr/share/webots/lib/controller`.